# angularjs components. how to trigger functions from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a supersimple component.

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {
    data: "&"
  },
  templateUrl: 'elements/views/my-component.html',
  controller: function() {

    const lol = function() {
      alert("You did it noob!");
    }

    $ctrl.$onInit = function() {
            $ctrl.lol = lol;
    }
});
```

Now I want to make new html,in folder `elements/views` named `my-component.html`

I am guessing something like :

```
<div ???="my-component.html">
  <button ng-click="$ctrl.lol">Press it</button>
</div>
```

What should I put on the ??? in HTML, how can I make this work?

What am I missing?

Long story short, I need to make component that removes the button, in case anyone wants to write a line of code more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach the lol method to **this** in the controller

```
angular.
  module('app',[]).
  component('myComponent', {
    template: '<div><button ng-click="$ctrl.lol()">Press it</button></div>',
    controller: function myCompCtrl() {
      this.lol = function() {
        alert("You did it noob!");
      };
    }
  });
```

Then in the view

```
<div ng-app="app">
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TAgjXrJK2F9aeWnT5teR?p=preview)

Comment: I can't seem to make it work, also you forgot "}".. Can you do the test in some codepen or something? Woul really appriciate it!

Comment: Thank you. Side question, why do i have to use module("app".. what if i have huge application do i just assig it to MyHugeApplication or how else? Is module really needed?

Comment: @joe123 In this example I just instantiate it as angular.module('app',[]). If you need to reuse it you could refere to it as angular.module('app'), or store the instans as a variable, app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
   <example></example>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var exampleComponent = {
    controller: function (){
      var ctrl = this;

      ctrl.doSomething = function () {
        alert('You are awesome');
      };
    },

    template: `
            <div>
              <button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething();">
              Click me
              </button>
            </div>`
};


angular.module('exampleApp', [])
  .component('example', exampleComponent)
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1h07t30z/755/

Comment: Hey Goediaz thanks for reply but i cant seem to make it work :(

Comment: Changed my answer and added a fiddle. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Goediaz!

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you just need to move where some of the bits and pieces are defined.

```
// In your .js file
app.component('myComponent', {
    bindings: {
        data: "&"
    },
    templateUrl: 'elements/views/my-component.html',
    controller: function() {

        /*
        Note that inside your controller function
        you just use `this` to refer to it - it's
        a regular JavaScript constructor function.

        In your template you can reference the controller with `$ctrl`.
        */

        this.lol = function() {
            alert("You did it noob!");
        }

        this.$onInit = function() {

        }
    }
});


<!-- elements/views/my-component.html -->
<button ng-click="$ctrl.lol()">Press it</button>


<!--
In your main application template (*outside* my-component.html)
-->
<my-component>
</my-component>
```

You can also invoke the `data` binding from inside your component template as `$ctrl.data()` (assuming you intended to define it as an expression? `data: "&"`)

Here is a plunker showing this example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/yrFDMS?p=preview